Nuxt and vuewordcloud error - 500 Unexpected token ':'
I have a web application in Vue.js using nuxt and vuetify.
I have installed the library vuewordcloud to make a word cloud : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuewordcloud
And now, when I start the project, it indicates an error : `500 Unexpected token ':'`.
Here is the full error message :
500
Unexpected token ':'

    at new Script (node:vm:99:7)
    at createScript (node:vm:255:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:303:10)
    at ViteNodeRunner.runModule (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:398:19)
    at ViteNodeRunner.directRequest (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:381:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ViteNodeRunner.cachedRequest (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:206:14)
    at async ViteNodeRunner.dependencyRequest (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:259:12)
    at async ./plugins/wordcloud.ts:2:31
    at async ViteNodeRunner.runModule (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:399:5)

Here is my plugins/wordcloud.ts configuration :
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import VueWordCloud from 'vuewordcloud';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component('VueWordCloud', VueWordCloud);
});

I've tried to use the same configuration but in Javascript.
But when I try to do that, the same error appears.
Is there any other way to make a wordcloud in Vue.js or any way to solve this problem ?

And you nuxt.config.js? :)

I’m voting to close this question because it is a known issue in an abandoned 3rd party library

Thanks @Phil, I haven't seen that post ! :D

I just need to rename the plugin file from wordcloud.ts to wordcloud.client.ts.
Here is the solution post : https://github.com/SeregPie/VueWordCloud/issues/67#issuecomment-2377346897
nuxt .client.ts usage in the name of a plugin file : https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins
Thanks to @Phil for the help.
